# How do you bind data from 2 JQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my example I am trying to bind `$('#integrate_employee_popup').modal('show');` with `$("#integrate_employee_popup").bind('show',function(e) {});`.  It used to be a block UI and now it is upgrade time to bootstrap JQuery to be more responsive.

The old command was a `$('#integrate_employee_popup').trigger('block')` and `$("#integrate_employee_popup").bind('block',function(e) {});`.  I must be missing some element here to plug it in.

```
$(".integrate_employee_link").click(function(e) {
  button_id = this.id;
  employee_question_id = this.id.split('_')[2];
  integrate_employee_target = ($(this).attr('target')===undefined)?'':$(this).attr('target');
  integrate_employee_onunblock = ($(this).attr('onunblock')===undefined)?'':$(this).attr('onunblock');
  integrate_employee_jsonID = ($(this).attr('jsonID')===undefined)?'jsonID':$(this).attr('jsonID');
  integrate_employee_columns = ($(this).attr('columns')===undefined)?'fname=First Name, lname=Last Name':$(this).attr('columns');
  integrate_employee_select = ($(this).attr('tooltype')===undefined)?'radio':$(this).attr('tooltype');
  integrate_employee_employeetype = ($(this).attr('employeetype')===undefined)?'basic':$(this).attr('employeetype');
  integrate_employee_searchresultlabel = ($(this).attr('searchresultlabel')===undefined)?'Existing Active Employees':$(this).attr('searchresultlabel');
  integrate_employee_selectmod = ($(this).attr('selectmod')===undefined)?'':$(this).attr('selectmod');
  integrate_employee_frommod = ($(this).attr('frommod')===undefined)?'':$(this).attr('frommod');
  integrate_employee_wheremod = ($(this).attr('wheremod')===undefined)?'':$(this).attr('wheremod');
  integrate_employee_secondquery = ($(this).attr('secondquery')===undefined)?'':$(this).attr('secondquery');
  integrate_employee_tool =($(this).attr('tool')===undefined)?'':$(this).attr('tool');
  integrate_jobtitleID = $('#integrate_employee_form #employee_form_jobtitleID').val();
  integrate_categoryID = $('#integrate_employee_form #employee_form_categoryID').val();
  integrate_shiftID = $('#integrate_employee_form #shiftID').val();
  $('#integrate_employee_popup').modal('show');
  return false;
});

$("#integrate_employee_popup").bind('show',function(e) {
  $('#target').val(integrate_employee_target);
  $('#jsonID').val(integrate_employee_jsonID);
  $('#employeesearchlabel').html(integrate_employee_searchresultlabel);
  $('#integrate_employee_desc').val('');
  integrate_employee_searchresults();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the `Bootstrap` documentation, you should be using `show.bs.modal` event, [check this list](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

So, assuming that the element with id `integrate_employee_popup` is already a `Bootstrap` modal, you can do:

```
$("#integrate_employee_popup").bind('show.bs.modal',function(e) {
   //your code goes here
}
```

Also, if my mind does not fail me, `return false` in `jQuery click` may stop event propagation.